# Sending message to msmq queue via msmqIntegrationBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, msmqintegrationbinding

So I'm trying to configure my client code to send messages to MSMQ queue. I followed the steps described in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp and my client code looks as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var binding = new MsmqIntegrationBinding("MyMessagesBinding");
        var address = new EndpointAddress(@"msmq.formatname:DIRECT = OS:.\private$\MyMessages");
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDataRelayService>(binding, address);
        var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        while (true)
        {
            var message = new MyMessage
            {
                Content = "this is content!!!",
                Id = "random uuid"
            };
            var msmqWrapper = new MsmqMessage<MyMessage>(message)
            {
                Priority = MessagePriority.Highest
            };

            channel.PassMessage(msmqWrapper);
            Console.WriteLine("message sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="MyResponseEndpoint"
                address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\MyMessages"
                binding="msmqIntegrationBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="MyMessagesBinding"
                contract="Client.IDataRelayService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <msmqIntegrationBinding>
        <binding name="MyMessagesBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </msmqIntegrationBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

IDataRelayService.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataRelayService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void PassMessage(MsmqMessage<MyMessage> message);
}
```

IDataRelayServiceChannel.cs:

```
public interface IDataRelayServiceChannel : IDataRelayService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}
```

It compiles and runs with no problem, but when I open up evet viewer there are no events logged for MSMQ. If I open computer management tool to view queues it shows 0 messages in my queue. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I enabled event tracing for MSMQ and here's what event viewer is showing me:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the messages are getting stored on the sender machine. Check the MSMQ service on the client's machine, and look for a temporary outbound queue. Your messages should be on it.

Comment: How can I see that? I'm looking at computer management / Message Queuing and I see no messages being held in my queue. Are you talking about some other tool by any chance?

Comment: Are you looking at the outgoing queues?

Comment: Outgoing queues is empty :(

Comment: And you have definitely enabled MSMQ event log on the receiver machine?

Comment: Well I right-clicked my queue name -> properties and checked the enabled checkbox in the journal section. Is that what you mean? Sorry, I'm quite new to this. Anyway - it's not showing any entries.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730882(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly permissions related.

The service account the message sender is running under must have the following MSMQ permissions on the queue it is trying to send to:

- Send Message
- Get Properties
- Get Permissions

If your sender is on a different domain to your receiver, you will need to grant these permissions to a local user called ANONYMOUS_LOGON.

Also, enable MSMQ E2E event logging: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730882(v=ws.11).aspx. This should tell you what is going on.

If you have WCF on both ends of the queue you should be using netMsmqBinding rather than msmqIntegrationBinding.

Comment: All my code and msmq queues are on one machine. I'm running my message sender under elevated priviledge.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch - Check the queue permissions. Grant the account you're running under full control over the queue.

Comment: Ok, will do it tomorrow when I'm back at work, and if it works - accept this answer.

Comment: I granted all the permissions to every user and turned on event logging. Still I have no idea what's going on :). Please see my updated question.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch can you look in the dead letter or transactional dead letter queue on the receiving machine? Are your messages there?

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch also what do the events say?

Comment: Ok, so I'm seeing my messages in the transactional dead letter queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130486/discussion-between-tom-redfern-and-szworny-dziach).

Comment: After I switched to using netMsmqBinding as you suggested during our chat the problem went away, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Maybe you could edit it to provide more accurate information to whoever gets here?